# open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (21: Is a directory)

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

When ever i install a new application using terminal command, i get this error

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (21: Is a directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What I tried is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But I cannot solve this. I made a refer to the other answers but it's not finding to workout. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried reboot or logout will also do

Comment: Yes! I am struggling with this for long time! I have tried rebooting and logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in terminal to find what is running

```
ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
```

If that doesn’t print anything, type the following in terminal to remove the lock

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Also

If you try

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

that will catch processes containing the word apt, at least. If you see an apt-get process or an aptitude process that looks stuck, you can try

```
sudo  kill processnumber
```

and if that doesn't work try

```
sudo kill -9 processnumber
```

This should kill the process and may remove the lock. Killing an apt or aptitude process is harmless unless it is actually in the middle of package installation.

Comment: `ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep` **says** `2676 ?        00:00:00 update-apt-xapi` **and**
`sudo kill -9 processnumber` **says** `kill: failed to parse argument: 'processnumber`

Comment: Then let that process finish, or if you don't want to wait kill it as said in answer, close synaptic, update manager and other system tools who use lock

Comment: I have only one user. How can i kill it?

Comment: read the answer buddy "sudo kill -9 <process id>" for your case "sudo kill -9 2676" ... I think the answer is easy if you know about process ID's (The number given to each running process) .. If it doesn't solve your issue update it accordingly

Comment: What i tried is `sudo  kill 2976` and `sudo kill -9 2676`. Then I tried to install  `sudo apt-get install somepakage`, Still same error

Comment: give output of   ps aux | grep apt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26758/discussion-between-prashant-chikhalkar-and-hemnath-mouli).